# How to create multiple printer profiles on Mac?

Tags: mac, printing

I have a Mac, but sometimes need to print with legal/landscape and other times with letter/portrait. In Windows I can create two printer profiles for the same printer to easily toggle between these. How best to do this with a Mac?

Answer (score 2):

While this is not a direct answer to your question, **you can create settings presets** for that -- **which can be selected** in every GUI app using the standard print dialog **as easily as a different printer**: [image]